# Php loop- same loop incrementing and then decrementing

Tags: php, loops

So my current coode is this:

```
<?php 
$x=1;
 while($x<=512)
{
    echo $x.'<br>';
    $x=$x*2;
}
while($x>=1)
{
    echo $x.'<br>';
    $x=$x/2;
 }
?>
```

> The result is simply this:
>   
> 1
>   
> 2
>   
> 4
>   
> 8
>   
> 16
>   
> 32
>   
> 64
>   
> 128
>   
> 256
>   
> 512
>   
> 1024
>   
> 512
>   
> 256
>   
> 128
>   
> 64
>   
> 32
>   
> 16
>   
> 8
>   
> 4
>   
> 2
>   
> 1

But what im trying to do is make a single loop as apposed to the currnet two 
'while' loops that it currently is. I was wondering if there is a way to both,  Increment and Decrement inside of the same loop in PHP? If so please explain how with a code snippet and explain. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? Won't doubling a variable and then halving it cancel it out effectively giving you an infinite loop?

Comment: Is it possible to increment and decrement in a loop, yes. You can do anything inside of a loop that you can do outside of a loop. Can you combine these into one loop, yes (I would run two variables increment one, decrement the other and concat the output in a string to echo later or change to a for loop with a set number of iterations and move up/down in that). However, sometimes it is better to just use two loops, even if just for clarity of code.

Comment: It was a dicussion topic in class today and i wanted to knwo if you can actually achieve this using only one loop.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn are you saying have say $x and $y, and then have one for going up to a number then having the other to go down one btu ow would ou put this inside of A SINGLE loop?? Can you create some code to show this?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was saying. However, any answer that combines those loops is going to just be a clever way to do it and likely more confusing in the long run. You won't be saving any performance or anything by combining the loops. And in fact it would be detrimental by making the code more unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Also, both of the loops don't loop the same number of times. The second loop will actually loop one more time than the first. Combining them becomes trickier and even more of a "hack"/"complication". You wouldn't be able to really do both the increment/decrement in a single loop at the same time but rather would have to loop the same number of times that both loops loop.

Comment: @jonathankuhn yes i see that it would make more sense to do it into two loops just wanted to see if i could do it as more of a challenge. But thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much what I was talking about. Still keeps the while portion of the loop the same as what you have. Just increment/decrement and saves output to another variable to be echo'd later.

```
<?php
$x = 1;
$y = 1024;
$outputX = '';
$outputY = '';

while($x <= 512){
    $outputX .= "{$x}<br>";
    $outputY .= "{$y}<br>";

    $x *= 2;
    $y /=2;

}

echo $outputX;
echo $outputY;
//need to output the last value of $y because the loop misses the last iteration of the second while loop.
echo $y;
```

Comment: Ah i see what you mean now definitely does make it a bit more complicated thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this but I don't see the practicality of it.

```
$x=1;
$r=1048576;
while($x<=1048576){
    if($x<=$r)
        echo $x.'<br>';
    else
        echo $r.'<br>';
    $x*=2;
    $r/=2;
}
```

Comment: @Crinkelycrewms Exactly like that thank you for the proof that it can be done but why is it that that $r has to be 1048576?

Answer (score 0):

Test to see if the upper limit has been reached.  If so, execute the division code.

```
$x=1;
$reverse = 0;
 while($x<=1025 && $x>=1)
{
    echo $x.'<br>';
    if($x == 1024){ $reverse= 1;}
    if($reverse == 0) {
        $x=$x*2;
    } else {
        $x=$x/2;       
    }
}
```